# How to initialize Java EE 5 JAX-WS 2.0 Web Service with Parameters

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, jax-ws, java-ee-5

**Application configuration:**

- Web application using java first method of creating JAX-WS 2.0 Web Services with annotations.
- WebLogic 10.3

**My Requirements**

The requirements I have are to deploy a single web service implementation class, but change logic based on the URL from which the service was accessed.

**Question:**
I'm assuming a good way to do this is to deploy different mappings in web.xml and initialize them with different parameters.  Is there a better way?

What is the best way to switch logic off the URL from which the web service was accessed?  Should I try to configure two servlet mappings in web.xml with initialization parameters (tried, but couldn't get it to work), or should I parse the URL in the service impl?  Any other alternatives?

**What I've Tried (but didn't work)**

I have tried adding the `<init-param>` in the `<servlet>` element in web.xml.  However, can't get to the `ServletConfig` object inside the web service to retrieve the param.  The web service does not have all the functionality of a standard `Servlet` (even if I implement `Servlet` or `ServletContextListener`).  I only have access to the `WebServiceContext` (it seems) and from there I can only get `<context-param>` elements--but I would need `<init-param>` elements instead.

In web.xml, I enter two `<servlet>` elements using the same Java class, but which map to two different URLs as follows.  Notice how the "source" param is different in each Servlet mapping.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Foo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.Foo</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>source</param-name>
   <param-value>1</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Foo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Foo</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Bar</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.Foo</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
        <param-name>source</param-name>
   <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Bar</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Bar</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You very well may have, but did you try using `MessageContext` at runtime to determine what the source is?

```
@WebService
public class CalculatorService implements Calculator
{

    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext context;

    @WebMethod
    public void getCounter()
    {
        MessageContext mc = wsContext.getMessageContext();
        // you can grab the HttpSession
        HttpSession session = (HttpServletRequest)mc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST)).getSession();
        // ...or maybe the path info is enough
        String path = mc.get(MessageContext.PATH_INFO);
        // the query itself should almost definitely be enough
        String query = (String) mc.get(MessageContext.QUERY_STRING);
    }

}
```

I got the idea from http://sirinsevinc.wordpress.com/category/jaxws/.  Haven't tried it, though.

Comment: This solution, or one similar, seems to be the only solution.  I would go with adding this logic to a Soap Handler that executes in a chain in the inbound request (setting a parameter in the message at that point).  Thanks for the thoughts.  I was hoping this would be a simple configuration, but it looks like there will be more to it than that.